# Does $du=(y-x^2)dx+(x+y^2)dy$ is an exact differential or not?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to show if the $du=(y-x^2)dx+(x+y^2)dy$ differential is exact or not. But as far as I understand, it is exact if the function $ u (x, y) $ exists such that the total differential is the one shown. So looking for who the role should be:

Since
$\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=y-x^2$ then
$u(x,y)=\int(y-x^2)dx+\phi(y)$
$u(x,y)=xy-\cfrac{1}{3}x^3+\phi(y)$

And partially deriving with respect to y:
$\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=x+\phi'(y)$

and equaling to $ x + y ^ 2 $

$x+\phi'(y)=x+y^2 \iff \phi'(y)=y^2$ and then $\phi(y)=\int y^2dy=\cfrac{1}{3}y^3+C$

And therefore the function $ u (x, y) $ will be:

$u(x,y)=xy-\cfrac{1}{3}x^3+\cfrac{1}{3}y^3+C$

Is that enough to show that it was accurate? Or how is it shown to be exact for before deducing the function $ u (x, y) $?

Comment: for nice functions like these, $u(x,y)=A dx+B dy$ is exact $ \iff \left(\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial y}\right)_x=\left(\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x}\right)_y$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner do you really mean the extra subscripts on the partials in your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work shows it is exact. But in general $a(x,y)dx+b(x,y)dy$ is exact when $\partial a(x,y)/\partial y=\partial b(x,y) / \partial x$ which can be checked directly without finding what you did.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I had the idea that only if the $ u $ function existed, you could tell if it was exact or not. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kami I think once the partials are known to be equal, the same process you used can be shown to always work in general to get something with total derivative the given differential.

Comment: Ok Ok, thank you very much for the advice!